# 3 IF statements together

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, I can get a partial on this using an `IF` statement, but I don't know how to put 3 together to give the result I'm looking for or even if it can be done so please go easy one me :-)

I hope the image works, I would like to update the 3 columns with Yes/No when there is a Yes value essentially that cell is 33.33% complete, so 2 x yes = 66.67 and 3 yes = 100%

```
       Started      Replied    Completed     % Complete  
P1     Yes          Yes        Yes           100  
P2     Yes          No         No            33%
```

I can get it to show me when there are 3 yes, but im struggling after that!

Please help :-)

```
=IF((AND(G3="Yes", H3="yes",I3="yes")), "100")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please handle every `IF` condition separately and just sum up the result of each one, e.g. as Excel formula:

```
=(IF(G3="Yes";100;0)+IF(H3="Yes";100;0)+IF(I3="Yes";100;0))
```

Divide it by the total number of given conditions afterwards (here 3):

```
=(IF(G3="Yes";100;0)+IF(H3="Yes";100;0)+IF(I3="Yes";100;0))/COUNTA(G3:I3)
```

Just use this for every line, means every person in your table and calculate the average of the `%` column at the end:

[image]